# Entity cannot resolve symbol SaveChanges

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I just added an entity object to my project. When I go to savechanges, it is telling me that it is not found.

Here is an example:

[image]

And the code:

```
[Authorize]
[SessionExpireFilter]
public ActionResult Delink()
{
  var control = Logging.StartLog();
  control.ClassName = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;

  try
  {
    if (CurrentCustomerSession.Current.AccountGuid == Guid.Empty)
    {
      Logging.WriteLog(control, "Redirecting to AddCustomer:Customer since CurrentAccountGuid == null");
      return RedirectToAction("AddCustomer", "Customer");
    }

    var username = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToLower();
    var entities = new SuburbanPortalEntities();
    var qry = (from x in entities.UsersAccountLinks
               where x.AccountId == CurrentCustomerSession.Current.AccountGuid && x.aspnet_Users.LoweredUserName == username
      select x).FirstOrDefault();
    if(qry == null)
      return View("Error");

    qry.AccountId = Guid.Empty;
    entities.SaveChanges();
    CurrentCustomerSession.Current.AccountGuid = Guid.Empty;
    CurrentCustomerSession.Current.AccountNumber = string.Empty;
    CurrentCustomerSession.Current.Branch = string.Empty;
    //return View("");
    return RedirectToAction("AccountScreen", "Customer");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Logging.WriteLog(control, string.Format("exception: {0}", ex.Message));
    Logging.WriteException(control, ex);
    return View("Error");
  }
  finally
  {
    Logging.WriteLog(control, "End Delink");
    Logging.FlushLog(control);
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what to check at this point. I have deleted SuburbanPortalEntities and readded it without any success.

Any suggestions where I look?

Comment: "When I go to savechanges", what does that mean? do you mean "When I compile my code using a call to SaveChanges?". Or are you talking about navigating? Check the error list and post the exact compilation error. Is the class `SuburbanPortalEntities` without errors?

Comment: What are you Saving, Is the query returning a null or does it not like the empty GUID set?

Comment: I'm not able to compile, this is a compile time error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, I had 6.1.x installed of Entity Framework. When I checked the nuget packages, it showed 6.2.0 available. Once I updated to that version of Entity Framework, it started working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by downgrading Entity Framework version from 6.2.0 to 6.1.0 and back to 6.2.0.